# what are the different ways of dictionary declaration in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

what is the difference between
1. `var dict : [Int:String] = [:]` , 
2. `var dict2 : [Int:String]` and
3. `var dict3 = Dictionary<Int,String>()` .

Anyone help me  to understand  what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**.

```
var dict : [Int:String] = [:]
```

This creates an empty dictionary of type [Int:String]

**2.**

```
var dict2 : [Int:String]
```

This creates a dictionary of type [Int:String]  but does not assign any value to it. Before using some value must be assigned to it.

**3.**

```
var dict3 = Dictionary<Int,String>()
```

This is just another way to create an empty dictionary same as in method-1. Method-1 is a shorthand form of Method-3